# Tensorflow classify image training

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow

Is there any way to add a new class to the existing 1000 classes of the inception v3 model in tensorflow..? or is it possible to fine tune the model by just adding more images to the existing category

Comment: who upvotes this stuff?

Comment: Curious, just want to know how it relates to git?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the tutorial [How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) on TensorFlow.

From the Tutorial:

> Modern object recognition models have millions of parameters and can take weeks to fully train. Transfer learning is a technique that shortcuts a lot of this work by taking a fully-trained model for a set of categories like ImageNet, and retrains from the existing weights for new classes. In this example we'll be retraining the final layer from scratch, while leaving all the others untouched. For more information on the approach you can see [this paper on Decaf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.1531v1.pdf).

Comment: but instead of training final layer from the scratch,can we take the same weights that we have for softmax anduse it